# Training a tip bearing apple tree

Tags: apples, espalier

I'm thinking of growing a tip bearing apple tree in my garden and was wondering if there are any training options that would suit it. The general advice is it's not possible to grow on a cordon, but I wondered if any other forms such as columns etc. would allow for this, as my garden is quite small. Otherwise I'll aim for a smaller tree instead.

Comment: What part of the world and what type of soil?

Answer (score 3):

Fans have more tips than cordons or espaliers, more tips = more fruit.

Many apples are partial tip bearers, even if listed as tip-bearers.

Tip-bearing trees are convenient because they should need less pruning: you let them grow shaggy.
Cordons and espaliers are all about pruning, and holding branches at angles to encourage fruiting spurs along the branch, so a few branches can make a lot of fruit.

You can use tip bearers for a cordon if you want that variety, it will only give you  a smaller yield, so pruning it into a three prong cordon is better.